# On creation of ContractLineItem getting FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION

Tags: apex, trigger

I am creating a ContractLineItem record on the creation of ServiceContract by using a trigger. Below is the error I am getting

> Error: Invalid Data. 
>   Review all error messages below to correct your data.
>   Apex trigger CreatingControlLineItems caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: CreatingControlLineItems: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, The price book entry is in a different price book than the one assigned to the Service Contract, or Service Contract has no price book assigned.: Price Book Entry ID: [PricebookEntryId]: Trigger.CreatingControlLineItems: line 30, column 1

Here is the trigger which I have written:

```
trigger CreatingControlLineItems on ServiceContract (after insert)
{
List<ContractLineItem> toinsertCLT = NEW List<ContractLineItem>();
MAP<id,ServiceContract> mapTriggerNew = NEW MAP<id,ServiceContract>();
MAP<string,string> mapProdwithPBE = NEW MAP<string,string>();
SET<String> productIDS = NEW SET<String>();
for(ServiceContract sc : [SELECT Id,Pricebook2Id,Product__c FROM ServiceContract WHERE Id IN: trigger.new])
{
    mapTriggerNew.put(sc.Id,sc);
    productIDS.add(sc.Product__c);
}
system.debug('mapTriggerNew - ' +mapTriggerNew);
for(PricebookEntry pbe : [SELECT Id,Name,Pricebook2Id,Product2Id FROM PricebookEntry WHERE Product2Id IN: productIDS])
{
    mapProdwithPBE.put(pbe.Product2Id,pbe.id);
}
system.debug('mapProdwithPBE - ' +mapProdwithPBE);
for(ServiceContract sc : mapTriggerNew.values())
{
    ContractLineItem cli = New ContractLineItem();
    cli.ServiceContractid = sc.Id;
    cli.PricebookEntryId = mapProdwithPBE.get(sc.Product__c);
    //cli.Product2Id =sc.Product__c;
    cli.Quantity = 1.00;
    cli.Description = 'test';
    cli.UnitPrice = 0.00;
    toinsertCLT.add(cli);
}
system.debug('toinsertCLT - ' +toinsertCLT);
insert toinsertCLT;
}
```

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: 1) You need to verify that the ServiceContract was saved with a Pricebook2Id and 2) you need to query for that ServiceContract.Pricebook2Id to locate the PricebookEntry(s) for the specific Product2 that each lineItem corresponds to

Comment: @cropredy I have tried as said but ContractLineItem  is getting Inserted.

Comment: I have edited the code, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - *untested*

allows for

- ServiceContracts without Pricebook2Id
- Multiple Pricebooks sharing the same Product2Id

does not allow for multiple currencies but extension should be straightforward

*I renamed some variables to be clearer*

```
trigger CreatingControlLineItems on ServiceContract (after insert) {}

    // collection to insert in bulk
    ContractLineItem[] contractLineItems = NEW List<ContractLineItem>();

    // Lookup map to find the right PBE in bulk manner
    Map<Id,Map<Id,PriceboookEntry> PbesByPriceBookIdByProductId = new Map<Id,Map<Id,PricebookEntry>>();

    // Search keys
    Set<Id> productIdS = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> pricebook2Ids = new Set<Id>();

    for(ServiceContract sc  : trigger.new]){
        if (sc.Pricebook2Id == null) {continue;}
        productIDS.add(sc.Product__c);
        pricebook2Ids.add(sc.Pricebook2Id);
    }

    //  Trigger batch could have service contracts with different pricebooks
    //  And a given product2Id could be on multiple pricebooks
    //  So we need a map of Product2Id => map <PriceBook2Id, PricebookEntry>
    for(PricebookEntry pbe : [SELECT Id,Name,Pricebook2Id,Product2Id 
       FROM PricebookEntry 
       WHERE Product2Id IN: productIdS AND
             Pricebook2Id IN : pricebook2Ids]){
        if (PbesByPriceBookIdByProductId.containsKey(pbe.Product2Id) {
            PbesByPriceBookIdByProductId.get(pbe.Product2Id}.put(pbe.Pricebook2Id,pbe));
        }
        else {
            PbesByPriceBookIdByProductId.put(pbe.Product2Id,
                    new Map<Id,PricebookEntry> {pbe.Pricebook2Id => pbe});
        }
    }
    // Build the lineItems using the correct PBE that matches parent's PricebOOk2Id and custom
    //  field Product__c
    for(ServiceContract sc : Trigger.new) {
        if (sc.Pricebook2Id == null) {continue;}
        contractLineItems.add( new ContractLineItem (
            ServiceContractid = sc.Id,
            PricebookEntryId = PbesByPriceBookIdByProductId.get(sc.Product__c).get(sc.Pricebook2Id).Id,
            Quantity = 1.00,
            Description = 'test',
            UnitPrice = 0.00));

    }
    insert contractLineItems;
}
```